# react-day-picker year select dropdown max height?

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I'm using [react-day-picker](https://react-day-picker.js.org/) in my react project and noticed the year select dropdown takes up the screen height on safari. Is there a way to add styling to this dropdown and add a max height to this dropdown? Thanks

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sun-48p2z5?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
const YearDropdown = ({ children }) => (
  <div style={{ maxHeight: '200px', overflowY: 'auto' }}>
    {children}
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React Day Picker Example</h1>
      <DayPicker
        dropdownContainer={YearDropdown}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

or you can use input date like this

```
  <div>
    <p>date</p>
    <input type='date' required onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)} value={date}/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work.

Comment: have you tried overflowY: 'scroll' ? maybe works

Comment: Yup, also didnt work. See my codesandbox

Comment: sorry styling and CSS doesn't works i tried many ways but still doesn't
look at this 
https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-external-form

Comment: I am using https://react-day-picker.js.org not reactdatepicker.com